# How to solve $y'=\sqrt{1-y^2} , y(0)=0$ by using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is initial value problem: (How to solve it by power series)

$y=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nx^n$

D.E: $y'=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ ,

Initial condition : $ y(0)=0$

How to show the solution is:

$y = \sin x $ by power series

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: I suppose a typo in the title : $y'$ and not $y2$ may be ?

Comment: yea corrected it

Comment: This is a separable equation, apply the standard technique.

Comment: hint: separation of variables.

Comment: Don't--or define precisely what you mean by "to do it by power series".

Comment: ((Comments by the OP now deleted.))

Answer (score 2):

**First point** : your equation is separable since $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$$ can write  $$dx=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$ Changing variable $y=\sin(t)$, $dy=\cos(t)dt$ will let you with $dx=dt$ so $$x+c=t=\sin^{-1}y$$ or $$y=\sin(x+t)$$ Applying the condition gives the expected result.

**Second point** :  using power series, write $$y=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a(i) x^i$$ (since $y(0)=0$) and square the equation $$y'^2=1-y^2$$ Replacing and expanding, you have $$0=\left(a(1)^2-1\right)+4 a(1) a(2) x+\left(a(1)^2+6 a(3) a(1)+4 a(2)^2\right) x^2+(2
   a(1) a(2)+12 a(3) a(2)+8 a(1) a(4)) x^3+\left(a(2)^2+16 a(4) a(2)+9 a(3)^2+2 a(1)
   a(3)+10 a(1) a(5)\right) x^4+(2 a(2) a(3)+24 a(4) a(3)+2 a(1) a(4)+20 a(2) a(5)+12
   a(1) a(6)) x^5+\left(a(3)^2+30 a(5) a(3)+16 a(4)^2+2 a(2) a(4)+2 a(1) a(5)+24 a(2)
   a(6)+14 a(1) a(7)\right) x^6+2 (a(3) a(4)+20 a(5) a(4)+a(2) a(5)+a(1) a(6)+18 a(3)
   a(6)+14 a(2) a(7)+8 a(1) a(8)) x^7+\left(a(4)^2+48 a(6) a(4)+25 a(5)^2+2 a(3)
   a(5)+2 a(2) a(6)+2 a(1) a(7)+42 a(3) a(7)+32 a(2) a(8)\right)
   x^8+O\left(x^9\right)+\cdots$$ Now, cancel the terms one after each other; you so obtain successively $$a(1)=1$$ $$a(2)=0$$ $$a(3)=-\frac{1}{6}$$ $$a(4)=0$$ $$a(5)=-\frac{1}{120}$$ and so on.

Comment: "and so on" must be some sort of dry humor. Not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}y=\sqrt{1-y^2} $$
$$ \frac{\frac{d}{dx}y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=dx $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=\int dx $$
$$ \arcsin(y)= x+C $$
$$ y= \sin(x+C) $$
Now let's solve for $C$
$$ \sin(0+C)=0 $$
$$ C= \arcsin(0)$$
$$ C= 0$$
Therefore 
$$ y= \sin(x+C) =\sin(x)$$

Comment: I wish you could see deleted answers!